# Can't understand C# Generics

Tags: c#, generics

I'm able to understand C# Generics but only when I read about it in a book where the examples are easy to follow. But in real life I get to see complicated C# Generics code like below. Can someone explain to me the generic aspects of this code? I see the  type parameter but don't understand why the T is not used in the body of the method. How is the T being used in the body?

```
public void ValidateExceptionFromResponse<T>( BaseClaimResponseDataContract<T> response )
    {
        if (response.CommunicationResponseCodes != null && response.CommunicationResponseCodes.Any())
        {
            var validateResult = new ValidationResults();
            foreach (var communicationResponseCodeDataContract in response.CommunicationResponseCodes)
            {
                validateResult.AddResult( new ValidationResult(communicationResponseCodeDataContract.Description.Current, null, null, null, null));
            }
            throw FaultManager.GenerateFault(validateResult);
        }
        if( response.MessageError != null )
        {
            throw FaultManager.GenerateFault(eErrorCodes.Claims, response.MessageError.Current);
        }
    }
```

Here is a snippet for BaseClaimResponseDataContract:

```
[KnownType(typeof(SummaryClaimsReportResponseDataContract))]
[KnownType(typeof(ClaimResponseDataContract))]
[KnownType(typeof(CommunicationResponseDataContract))]
[DataContract]
public class BaseClaimResponseDataContract<T>
{
    [DataMember]
    public bool IsRxClaim { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public ThirdPartyDataContract ThirdParty { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public ExternalSystemMessages RequestMessage { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool RequestAccepted { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ResponseStatus { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string ResponseCodes { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string[] ResponseCodesArray
    {
        get
        {
            var lstMessageCodes = new List<string>();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ResponseCodes))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < ResponseCodes.Length / 2; i++)
                {
                    var code = ResponseCodes.Substring(i*2, 2);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(code))
                        lstMessageCodes.Add(code);
                }
            }

            return lstMessageCodes.ToArray();
        }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public IEnumerable<CommunicationResponseCodeDataContract> CommunicationResponseCodes;

    [DataMember]
    public StringDataContract MessageError { get; set; }

    public void CopyFrom(BaseClaimResponseDataContract<T> claimResponse)
    {
        IsRxClaim = claimResponse.IsRxClaim;
        ThirdParty = claimResponse.ThirdParty;
        RequestMessage = claimResponse.RequestMessage;
        RequestAccepted = claimResponse.RequestAccepted;
        ResponseStatus = claimResponse.ResponseStatus;
        ResponseCodes = claimResponse.ResponseCodes;
        CommunicationResponseCodes = claimResponse.CommunicationResponseCodes;
        MessageError = claimResponse.MessageError;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why should `T` matter in the method?  `T` can be anything.

Comment: ValidateExceptionFromResponse<T> doesn't really do anything with generics here; BaseClaimResponseDataContract<T> is what you want to look at. It's just that because ValidateExceptionFromResponse takes a parameter of type BaseClaimResponseDataContract<T>, it will itself need to be declared as a generic. Post the code for BaseClaimResponseDataContract<T> and we can give you a fuller answer.

Comment: I think Ray is saying -- why is there a T if its not used or referenced in the implementation.  This is a weird example.

Comment: I added the code for the BaseClaimResponseDataContract if it helps to explain.

Comment: The generic class never uses its parameter T. Makes no sense. Move the parameter to the CopyFrom method.

Answer (score 6):

In this situation, it seems the only purpose of the generic argument is to enforce that the parameter to the method must be a `BaseClaimResponseDataContract<T>`. I suspect multiple types in your solution inherit from this, for example:

```
public class SomeSample : BaseClaimResponseDataContract<AnotherClass> 
{
}
```

The method can only be called with instances that implement this base type, so it's like a form of marking classes with an interface.

Comment: Actually yes, there are multiple types that inherit from this generic class. And this form of derivation allows us to reuse the code in the base (generic) class. Ok, so does it always lead to a non-generic class in the hierarchy of generic classes?

Comment: Negative. You can inherit from a generic base class and continue forward with an unbound type - for example `SomeSample<U> : BaseClaimResponseDataContract<U>` - you can continue this indefinitely until you find the final declaration where you specify the concrete type, like `var x = new SomeSample<int>` which is also a `BaseClaimResponseDataContract<int>`.

Answer (score 2):

The method was made generic because it takes a generic argument. In order to specify the type of the argument a generic is used which means the method much take a generic argument itself.

Answer (score 2):

In the case, it's not the method so much that's generic: it's the argument. The method is generic simply so that it can accept a type that is generic. You don't need to use the `T` argument within the method, because it's enough to know about the `BaseClaimResponseDataContract` part.

Comment: Is it safe to say that only generic methods can have generic parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, generics are used to conserve type information and flow it around. You get the same type out of a list that you put in.

In your case that is not apparent. `T` seems to be unused except to close the generic type.

Maybe `BaseClaimResponseDataContract<T>` has no useful non-generic base class. You can't use an open generic type, so you have to close it with a generic type parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter whether T is used in the method or not. We can have a generic function like this:

```
int dummy<T> (List<T> a)
{
    return a.Count * 2;
}
```

As you can see, T is not used anywhere in the method.Your example might also be something like this. Read on if you need more explanation:
Look at it this way: you have a generic type, and you want to write a method which takes a parameter of such a type, here BaseClaimResponseDataContract<>. Now, you can either write different methods, each for a concrete instance of this type, e.g.

```
public void ValidateExceptionFromResponse( BaseClaimResponseDataContract<int> response ) 
{ ... }
public void ValidateExceptionFromResponse( BaseClaimResponseDataContract<float> response ) 
{ ... }
public void ValidateExceptionFromResponse( BaseClaimResponseDataContract<String> response ) 
{ ... }
```

which of course in not efficient, or let the method be a generic one, i.e. can take instances of BaseClaimResponseDataContract<> made from all types. Let's call this type T, then we can write

```
public void ValidateExceptionFromResponse<T>( BaseClaimResponseDataContract<T> response )
```